# Page will blink when the button is clicked to execute function but expected result never happens

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a website (just for fun and learning) that basically is a t-shirt online store
I have a basic form setup which gets various data from the user
then runs a function called calcTaxes() which supposedly right now is going to mulitply the cost of the shirt by the quantity and spit it right underneath the button
But when I click the button Calculate taxes , all it is doing is it blinks once and resets the form
Perhaps someone can give me a little pointer in my code as to where I can change or fix?
Thank you in advance

```
function calcTaxes() {
cost = 10;
var taxed = cost * document.getElementById("qty");
document.getElementById("tax").innerHTML = taxed;
```

}

```
 <form>
    Name: <input type="text" placeholder="Your name here" required><br><br>
    Address: <textarea placeholder="Your Address" required></textarea><br><br>
    Email: <input type="email" placeholder="Your email address" required><br><br>
    <label for="size">Choose a size: (Same Price) </label>
    <select id="size" name="size">
        <option value="XS">XS -Extra Small</option>
        <option value="S">S-Small</option>
        <option value="M">M-Medium</option>
        <option value="L">L-Large</option>
        <option value="XL">XL-Extra Large</option>
        <option value="XXL">XXL-Extra Extra Large</option>
    </select><br><br>
    Color: <input type="radio" value="Black" name="color">Black
    <input type="radio" value="White" name="color">White
    <input type="radio" value="Gun-Metal" name="color">Gun-Metal 
    <br><br>
    Quantity: <input id="qty" type="number"><br><br>
    Shipping: <input type="radio" value="Ground" name="shipping">Ground ($10)
    <input type="radio" value="Overnight" name="shipping">Overnight ($20)
    <input type="radio" value="Drone-Drop" name="shipping">Drone-Drop ($25)
    <br><br>
    <button class="taxes" onclick="calcTaxes()">Calculate Taxes</button><br>



</form>
<p id="tax"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing .value on `document.getElementById("qty");`
To get value of that input filed:

```
 document.getElementById("qty").value;
```

Also remove your button out of the form, it was trying to submit it.
It is working now (I removed required fields, just add quantity and press button):

```js
function calcTaxes() {
cost = 10;
var taxed = cost * document.getElementById("qty").value;
document.getElementById("tax").innerHTML = taxed;

}
```

```html
<form>
    Name: <input type="text" placeholder="Your name here" ><br><br>
    Address: <textarea placeholder="Your Address"></textarea><br><br>
    Email: <input type="email" placeholder="Your email address" ><br><br>
    <label for="size">Choose a size: (Same Price) </label>
    <select id="size" name="size">
        <option value="XS">XS -Extra Small</option>
        <option value="S">S-Small</option>
        <option value="M">M-Medium</option>
        <option value="L">L-Large</option>
        <option value="XL">XL-Extra Large</option>
        <option value="XXL">XXL-Extra Extra Large</option>
    </select><br><br>
    Color: <input type="radio" value="Black" name="color">Black
    <input type="radio" value="White" name="color">White
    <input type="radio" value="Gun-Metal" name="color">Gun-Metal 
    <br><br>
    Quantity: <input id="qty" type="number"><br><br>
    Shipping: <input type="radio" value="Ground" name="shipping">Ground ($10)
    <input type="radio" value="Overnight" name="shipping">Overnight ($20)
    <input type="radio" value="Drone-Drop" name="shipping">Drone-Drop ($25)
    <br><br>
<br>

</form>
    <button class="taxes" onclick="calcTaxes()">Calculate Taxes</button>
<p id="tax"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks , I knew it was going to be something simple like that